# OpenSSL issue while uploading apk

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

So-many times I have tried to upload my .apk file into Google play but it's rejected by  OpenSSL error. I am novice developer. can I have the answer please?

Thanks!
Awadh

Comment: What kind of OpenSSL error? Can you post the exact error message? and how does this relate to Javascript and ActionScript 3?

Comment: Actionscript:    "We rejected Crackers Time, package ID air.CrackerTime, for violating our dangerous products policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users.

Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. "

Comment: As I tried to upload APK several times. but I am getting the error as followings.

Comment: APP REJECTED

Your app submission has been rejected because it contains security vulnerabilities, which is a violation of our dangerous products policy. If the uploaded APK was an app update, the previous version is still available on Google Play. More details about this rejection have been emailed to the account owner.

Comment: What technologies are you using? Which ANEs are included?

Comment: Apparently your app is a "dangerous product", as said by Google. What have you made?

Comment: Does your APK access some **https** server? Did you try to fake it by taking a standard (http) server and threw in OpenSSL to make it look good? But Google didnt like it? Maybe your solution is to use a webspace host that provides a real https server? The list of vulnerabilities is what's missing in your question (you can click **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33753042/edit)** to add new details). One of them might be a clue

Comment: Can we delete the previous version of .apl file from play store?

Answer (score 0):

Use the last version of adobe air sdk Compiler: download it from [Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) . this will solve your problem then update your app

Comment: several time I tried to upload the apk file but rejected....no idea what should I do?.....OpenSSL
The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:

$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

Comment: First of all which program do you use to compile your spk file. I use adobe air and had this problem before adobe air sdk 13 .then this problem has been solved since adobe air sdk 13 up to 19

Comment: I am using adobe flash CS6, Actionscript 3.0.

Comment: Just update your air compiler , As I told you I had this problem before then it's solved .1) Download the new compiler sdk  and decompress it  2) Add it to adobe flash pro compilers  from "help/Manage AIR SDK" and press the + button  3) change your target Air to the new version   .  (if this doesn't work update your adobe flash pro to "CC version"